# Prefixing a section title with an Icon

Tags: graphics, sectioning, cross-referencing

I'm trying to mark certain sections with a specific icon. I want the icon to show up in the text itself only, not in the Table of Contents (though the section itself should) and not in name references to the section. It should be right before the section title on the same line. This command I use below mostly works the way I want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphbox}

\graphicspath{{icons/}{images/}}

\newcommand{\invisiblesection}[1]{
  \refstepcounter{section}
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
  \sectionmark{#1}\phantom{}
}


\newcommand{\noticesubsection}[1]{
  \vspace{1em}
  \includegraphics[align=b, width=1em, height=1em]{example-image}~\textbf{\large #1}\invisiblesection{#1}
  \vspace{0.5em} \\
}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \noticesubsection{Sample}\label{samepleref}
    Some Text and a sample Name Reference: \nameref{samepleref}

\end{document}
```

Do note that I do not use numbered sections in my document, so if the numbers don't show up it doesn't matter to me. But I use plenty of references by section name, and those do not work in this case. I believe there is a way to do it by using \subsection commands in itself, so that regular section title formatting also would apply to this should it be changed. How could I do it that way?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that can be compiled and improved. We don't know who is `\invisiblesection`, for instance.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that invisiblesection was non-standard. Added that definition.

Comment: Thanks, but please provide a minimal example that can be compiled *as is*. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Otherwise, every person who wants to help you has to reconstitute a working example. This is a big waste of time, and other people won't be helped due to this.

Comment: Example updated to be able to output a full document

Comment: Your command is named `\noticesubsection`, but it should create a section, right? And this should be applicable to only a subset of all sections?

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following. `\noticesection` is used like `\section`—including the starred form to mean “unnumbered”—except that it takes an additional optional argument at the end, which is the label to use (if non-empty). You *must* use this argument to define the label of a “noticeable” section (i.e., one started with `\noticesection`); if you just use `\label` after calling `\noticesection`, it won't work.

As shown in the examples below:

- “noticeable sections” are always listed in the table of contents—as you asked;
- both numbered and unnumbered “noticeable sections” are supported;
- they play nicely with normal `\section`s (also with `\section*`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{xparse}           % only needed for LaTeX older than 2020-10-01
% 'expand' is needed for the \GetTitleStringDisableCommands technique
\usepackage[expand]{gettitlestring}
% Hyperref options: only for aesthetics
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__onepie_insert_icon:
  {
    \makebox[0pt][r]
      {
        \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image}
        \skip_horizontal:n { 1em }
      }
  }

% Make sure the commands inserting the icon don't leak inside the nameref of
% unnumbered sections.
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \__onepie_insert_icon: \c_empty_tl }

% #1: optional star for an unnumbered “noticeable section”
% #2: optional title used in headers and table of contents
% #3: title used in text
% #4: optional label
\NewDocumentCommand \noticesection { s O{#3} m O{} }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { % unnumbered
        \section*{\__onepie_insert_icon: #3}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
        \sectionmark{#2}
      }
      { % numbered
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__onepie_orig_@seccntformat:n \@seccntformat % back up

        \cs_set_protected:Npn \@seccntformat ##1
          {
            \__onepie_insert_icon:      % before the section number
            \use:c { the##1 } \quad
          }
        \section[#2]{#3}
        \cs_set_eq:NN \@seccntformat \__onepie_orig_@seccntformat:n % restore
      }

    \tl_if_empty:nF {#4} { \label{#4} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Normal section}
\label{sec:normal-first}

\noticesection*{An unnumbered ``noticeable'' section}[sec:unnum-nsection]

\section{Other normal section}
\label{sec:normal-second}

\noticesection{A numbered ``noticeable'' section}[sec:num-nsection]

\leavevmode\indent              % only for aesthetics
%
First normal section is number~\ref{sec:normal-first},
named \nameref{sec:normal-first}.

Second normal section is number~\ref{sec:normal-second},
named \nameref{sec:normal-second}.

The unnumbered ``noticeable'' section is named \nameref{sec:unnum-nsection}.

The numbered ``noticeable'' section is number~\ref{sec:num-nsection} and named
\nameref{sec:num-nsection}.

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

In case you want unnumbered “noticeable sections” to be indented as follows in the table of contents, replace the `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}` in the definition of `\noticesection` with this:

```latex
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#2}
```

[image: screenshot]

Finally, if you use a class such as `book` that prints chapter and section titles in headers and want to see this for an unnumbered “noticeable section”:

[image]

rather than that:

[image]

(where 1.2 is the number of the *previously*-numbered section), you can use this variant of the previous code:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{xparse}           % only needed for LaTeX older than 2020-10-01
\usepackage{lipsum}
% 'expand' is needed for the \GetTitleStringDisableCommands technique
\usepackage[expand]{gettitlestring}
% Hyperref options: only for aesthetics
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__onepie_prev_secnumdepth_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__onepie_insert_icon:
  {
    \makebox[0pt][r]
      {
        \includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image}
        \skip_horizontal:n { 1em }
      }
  }

% Make sure the commands inserting the icon don't leak inside the nameref of
% unnumbered sections.
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \__onepie_insert_icon: \c_empty_tl }

% #1: optional star for an unnumbered “noticeable section”
% #2: optional title used in headers and table of contents
% #3: title used in text
% #4: optional label
\NewDocumentCommand \noticesection { s O{#3} m O{} }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { % unnumbered
        \section*{\__onepie_insert_icon: #3}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#2}
        \int_set_eq:NN \l__onepie_prev_secnumdepth_int \c@secnumdepth
        \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % disable numbering in header
        \sectionmark{#2}
        % Restore secnumdepth
        \int_gset_eq:NN \c@secnumdepth \l__onepie_prev_secnumdepth_int
      }
      { % numbered
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__onepie_orig_@seccntformat:n \@seccntformat % back up

        \cs_set_protected:Npn \@seccntformat ##1
          {
            \__onepie_insert_icon:      % before the section number
            \use:c { the##1 } \quad
          }
        \section[#2]{#3}
        \cs_set_eq:NN \@seccntformat \__onepie_orig_@seccntformat:n % restore
      }

    \tl_if_empty:nF {#4} { \label{#4} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Normal section}
\label{sec:normal-first}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Other normal section}
\label{sec:normal-second}

\lipsum[1-7]

\noticesection*{An unnumbered ``noticeable'' section}[sec:unnum-nsection]

\lipsum[1-7]

\noticesection{A numbered ``noticeable'' section}[sec:num-nsection]

\leavevmode\indent              % only for aesthetics
%
First normal section is number~\ref{sec:normal-first},
named \nameref{sec:normal-first}.

Second normal section is number~\ref{sec:normal-second},
named \nameref{sec:normal-second}.

The unnumbered ``noticeable'' section is named \nameref{sec:unnum-nsection}.

The numbered ``noticeable'' section is number~\ref{sec:num-nsection} and named
\nameref{sec:num-nsection}.

\end{document}
```