# How to create section titles with Icons but no Icons in Table of context

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, sectioning, section-titles

I would like to know how I can create the following types of section headings
[image]

Note that the image is loaded using the graphics package. I have tried the following

```
\section{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Images/introduction}\quad Introduction}
```

Unfortunately, this code shows with the image in the table of contents. What I want is the code not to show with the image in the table of contents and the Image to be on the left of the section title. I would appreciate it if this can be done like a macro as I have a big document so everywhere with sections I want this to repeat

Comment: Looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531625/73317 (by an ungrateful question asker).

Comment: @frougon. Thank you. The solution only works for unnumbered ones I have just tried it. Is it possible to modify it so it works for all?

Comment: @frougon I want for the numbered sections the Icon comes before the number as shown in the picture I attached

Comment: The solution works both for numbered and unnumbered sections. The icon is printed to the left of the section number, as shown in the pictures of [my answer there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531655/73317).

Comment: @frougon I am trying your solution in The Legrand Orange Book available at https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book. Can it happen that something is clashing with numbered sections? Please put your answer here so that I can mark your answer at the end. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the `LegrandOrangeBook.cls` file use `titlesec` package to customize the section heading. You could simple replace the corresponding codes in `LegrandOrangeBook.cls` file from line 211 to 226 with following code:

```
\titleformat
    {\section} % Section type being modified
    [block] % Shape type, can be: hang, block, display, runin, leftmargin, rightmargin, drop, wrap, frame
    {\bfseries\sffamily\Large} % Format of the whole section
    {\llap{\textcolor{ocre}{\thesection}\hspace{1em}}} % Format of the section label
    {0cm} % Space between the title and label
    {\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image}\quad#1} % Code before the label
    [] % Code after the label
\titleformat
    {name=\section, numberless} % Section type being modified
    [block] % Shape type, can be: hang, block, display, runin, leftmargin, rightmargin, drop, wrap, frame
    {\bfseries\sffamily\Large} % Format of the whole section
    {\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image}\quad#1} % Format of the section label
    {0cm} % Space between the title and label
    {} % Code before the label
    [] % Code after the label
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed